# Relationship between *segulah* and violet color

Tags: etymology, color, segulah, drush

We have a tradition, very often used in *drush*, that words deriving from the same root are really manifestations of the same idea in different facets.

In this context, what is the relationship between the words *segulah* (not sure of a good translation, means usually some kabbalistic custom) and *segol* (violet)? In the same vein, the word is used to mean "unique" in Shemos 19:5. What is the connection between these and the vowel *segol*?

Comment: Can you source this tradition?

Comment: Where do you see _segol_ meaning violet?

Comment: @DoubleAA I heard this in shiurim from at least 3 of my rabbeim, not directly connected toceach other. Not sure about violet in Tanach, but is that the meaning used in Modern Hebrew?

Comment: The Hebrew-etymology blog [Balashon](http://www.balashon.com/2006/08/sagol.html) discusses the word סגל. He says that [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20120407065044/http://www.tora.us.fm/tnk1/messages/7046.html) tries to connect it to _am segulah_, but he doesn't think it's convincing.

Comment: @Rish this is very nice, if you write it as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it. It's not drushy but is nicely etymological.

Comment: In Masechet Gittin (fifth perek) _segulah_ means "saved assets".

Comment: @Mordechai yes, Tanach uses it to mean "treasure"